# Assert and de-assert in reset

Tags: signal, reset, linux

I'm reading linux reset controller driver codes and found assert and deassert:

```
/**
 * struct reset_control_ops - reset controller driver callbacks
 *
 * @reset: for self-deasserting resets, does all necessary
 *         things to reset the device
 * @assert: manually assert the reset line, if supported
 * @deassert: manually deassert the reset line, if supported
 * @status: return the status of the reset line, if supported
 */
struct reset_control_ops {
    int (*reset)(struct reset_controller_dev *rcdev, unsigned long id);
    int (*assert)(struct reset_controller_dev *rcdev, unsigned long id);
    int (*deassert)(struct reset_controller_dev *rcdev, unsigned long id);
    int (*status)(struct reset_controller_dev *rcdev, unsigned long id);
};
```

If I understand correctly:

- Assert is used to guarantee registers to be set/clear to reset/default value in case bootloader/BIOS/UEFI change their values and forget to restore in exit services.
- De-assert is used to help controllers go back to work state after resetting, like bring up PCIe link.

Is there something wrong about my understanding?

Comment: I would say that this has nothing to do with electronic design as it is a generic Linux drivers question. This should probably be posted in https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DoxyLover I think deassert and assert are electronic jargon, driver codes are just about configurations hardware registers here. So the point is still electronic.

Comment: To 'assert' a signal means to make that signal active - to do something. And to 'de-assert' a signal means to make it passive - to stop doing something. So in this specific context where you're asserting or de-asserting a reset line, it's likely that your understanding is roughly correct.

Comment: @brhans Hi, so for reset, `assert` is to make reset passive, and `deassert` make reset stop, right?

Comment: No, in this context to 'assert' the reset means to do the reset now - the reset signal is active not passive. The rest of the system might be passive while the reset is active though.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for the explanation. Another question is will deassert always come followed by assert? IOW, is it possible for some reset to only assert, and no deassert later?

Comment: If you assert (turn on) the reset it will (usually) keep the device in reset so you can't do anything with it until you deassert (turn off) the reset.